# Selenium(Python) error page covers main page

Tags: python, selenium

I'm automating some test with Selenium in Python.
During that proccess, an error page appears but not as a new pop-up window. It covers my page with another html page (In WebInspector->Networking I can see a request to download a whole another css file). 
In other words:
An error page covers my main window(original html is not visible) and I don't know how to switch to that error page.

I hope I'm understandable.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post image?

Comment: Not really, because it applies to my job.

Comment: How do you deal with the error page as an user? Is there a close button on it? Can you identify any elements on the error page using the inspector? I am afraid you will have to update the question with the HTML of the error page and/or your code trials to solve the problem

Comment: Yes, as a user I can close it. It creates a layer on my whole application window. It's like disabling an add with adblocker. You choose a portion of a screen to make it disappear. The point is: I don't know how to switch to that layer. It will be possible to close that error page once I can switch to it and then switch back to my app window.

Comment: @Tobiasz did you try `driver.switch_to.active_element()`? It might be possible to simply get the css/xpath locator of the close button of that error message and call `.click()` method on it without you having to explicitly switch to it. Did you try doing that? And again, update your question with your trial codes so far